# Error in the pom.xml generated by Spring Initializr

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, kotlin, pom.xml

I'm using Spring Tool Suite, and I want to make a REST API with Kotlin, Spring and Maven, but my pom.xml has an error after create the project via Spring Initializr. My "parent" tag raise an error, but I guess the problem come from the kotlin-maven-plugin. I can't figure what's wrong with this pom.xml. If someone could help me fixing this, I'll be grateful!

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>fr.asi</groupId>
<artifactId>api_kotlin_test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>api_kotlin_test</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.2.51</kotlin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                </args>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And I have this error:

```
Project configurator "org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.projectConfigurator" required by plugin execution "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.2.51:test-compile (execution: test-compile, phase: test-compile)" is not available. To enable full functionality, install the project configurator and run Maven->Update Project Configuration.
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to install Kotlin plugin in STS?

Comment: Check on plain command line....

Comment: Yes, I already installed the kotlin plugin.

Comment: What do you mean @khmarbaise?

Answer (score 3):

I add a property in the pom.xml as below:

`<maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>`

After adding this property, just save your pom.xml and update your project. The error should be resolved.
Below is a snippet from the pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.in28minutes.learning.jpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa-in-10-steps</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jpa-in-10-steps</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the error by adding a "plugingManagement" tag to enclose the "plugins" tags like following:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
     .......
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Note: This changing just removed the error, but I'm still unable to run the code (the "Run as Kotlin Application" option in Eclipse doesn't exist in my case.) I'm not sure if those errors are related, but I can't confirm they're not.

**Edit: I just avoid this issue by switching my IDE to IntelliJ IDEA, it seems that the Kotlin plugin of Eclipse is not perfect for now... All is fine now, and the "pluginManagement" tag is useless now.**